# How to get the GET request passed list data?

Tags: javascript, python, django

If I use the params for pass a list in GET method:

```
fetch_physicalserver_list(){

    var params = {
      id_list: this.physicalserver_id_list // there is [24, 26, 27]
    }

    this.$Lml_http('get', this.$Api_urls.user_productmanage_physicalserver.list(), params,  response => {
      this.physicalserver_list = response.data.results
      console.log( response.data.results)
    }, error => {

    })
}
```

And in the request, the `id_list` convert to the `id_list[]=24&id_list[]=27&id_list[]=27`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and I don't know how to get the `id_list` in the backend.

I use the method to get the `id_list[]` I will only get the first `id`, if I get  `id_list`, I will get nothing.
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the code of `get_param_from_query_params` method:

```
def get_param_from_query_params(query_params, param):

    param_temp = None

    try:
        mutable = query_params._mutable
        query_params._mutable = True

        param_list = query_params.pop(param)
        param_temp = param_list[0] if (isinstance(param_list, list) and len(param_list) > 0) else ''

        query_params._mutable = mutable
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    return param_temp
```

---

So, I have two questions:

1.The params's id_list converted to `id_list[]`. where is the official description?
2.How can I get the `id_list` after I passed to the backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are using the key `id_list[]`, so you must use `id_list[]` to retrieve the key in Django. Including `[]` in JavaScript is a convention to show there are multiple values, but it makes no difference to Django.

If you want a list of values instead of a single value, then use [`pop_item`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.popitem) instead of [`pop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.pop).

It's not clear to me why you need the `get_param_from_query_params` method. You are returning `param_list[0]` which means you'll only ever get a single item. It would be much simpler to use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
id_list = query_params.getlist('id_list')
```